# RS232 : dedicated signal ground or common with power ground?

Tags: noise, ground, isolation, rs232, digital-isolator

I'm designing the PCB for a robot, where I plan to add some connectors for external RS232 tools (provided by the client).

Each connector will provide power (either 24 or 48V, at 5A max) and an RS232 connection.

Do I need to add a "signal" ground wire for the RS232, or can I share it with the power ground?

RS232 being rather robust to noise, I suspect that it will work just fine, but on the other hand, I have no control at all about what load will be connected (excepted that I will limit the current to 5A), so the current might vary quite brutally.

Cable length will not exceed 2m.

Comment: We can't know how you are going to use the two grounds. If you have two ground wires, you can use one for RS232 comms and one for returning motor current, but then how will you do the motor module as you likely need to connect a MCU to RS232 and the motor anyway, so it really depends how you are going to use them.

Comment: On the robot side, if we use 2 ground wires, both are connected together (as on the current robot). On the tool side, I have no control at all what is going to happen, as we integrate whatever tool/sensor the client asks for (or sometimes the client adds tools himself). Some tools have a single ground (in which case we connect only the power ground), others have one power ground and one signal ground (sometimes even isolated) : in this case, if we keep 2 grounds, then we connect logic to logic and power to power ; if we go to one ground wire, then we connect everything together

Comment: I generally tend to keep signal grounds and power grounds separate because power ground carries the return current, therefore it can be "fluctuating" which sometimes can lead to communication errors. I'm not sure if this can be the case for a relatively slow and high-amplitude communication such as RS-232.

Comment: @RohatKılıç : that's precisely the point : for any "usual" signal (low voltage, high speed), I would not want to share ground with an unknown 5A load. RS232 however is a rather robust. If I can remove this extra wire, then I could add some extra functionnality on each connector. But if it's too risky, I'd rather keep the extra wire

Comment: Well... what's the power doing? Filtered at both ends, heavy switching, the works? Are there any other ground paths (chassis, other connectors) that might make a loop? Is everything more-or-less common-ground or is isolation needed?

Comment: On the robot side, I will probably add a big capacitor. On the other side, it might be anything, from low current sensors, to a robotic arm or a turning brush. Anything with peak currents bellow 5A is allowed (so some poorly designed motor controller with heavy switching and no filtering is possible). There will be no other ground path to make a loop. Everything is common ground (excepted for IR drops in cables)

Comment: @Sandro But if you do provide two ground wires that connect together at your connector, but can't control how clients design their equipment, it does not matter if there is one or two grounds. Clients could connect the two grounds at their connector too. Clients may forget to connect the big ground wire and all 5A flows through small ground wire. If the client sensor powers a MCU from the 5A positive wire, then it uses the 5A ground return wire for power, and if it still needs to communicate over RS232, it will already be connected without the small ground wire.

Comment: @Justme : so you would suggest going for a single ground wire?

Comment: @Sandro Not really. If you do that, you need a big 5A wire just for RS232 if you do not even use the supply. And it will prevent your submodules from having isolated comms interface from power. And if you plug in connector so that +48V connects first before the single ground wire, that's going to explode most RS-232 transceiver chips rated for 30V.

Answer (score 1):

I would always provide ground for the RS232 signal to minimize the path inductance and minimize interference (i.e. the minimum RS232 connector would normally have Tx, Rx & Gnd).

However, in your case, a key question will be whether the client-provided PSU and RS232 kit are isolated from each other.  If they share a common ground (which your question implies), then potentially a significant fraction of the motor return current could flow in the RS232 "Gnd" wire (whether this is separate or combined). This can cause problems due to shifts in the reference level, especially if the motor current has lots of transients.  It may also burn out the wire.

RS232 *is* pretty tolerant, so you might not have issues, but for industrial environments, my default approach is always to have galvanic isolation on control interfaces to avoid this kind of problem.

It comes from free with Ethernet (which is transformer isolated), and there are off-the-shelf [isolator chips for RS232](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/12993#/) (including charge pump supplies for Tx) that work very well.

**Summary:** Do provide a "return"/"gnd" wire for your RS232 interface, but galvanically isolate the RS232 interface from the rest of your circuit to avoid "entertaining" problems in the field.

Comment: OP: Welcome to the wonderful world of ground loops.  Where avoidance is expensive, mitigating is tedious, ignoring is ignorance, and when customer equipment integration is involved: nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: Also, my fellow enginerds (and OP), let RS232 fade away already.  Switch to Ethernet (or some industrial version of it), and save yourself all of these nasty ground loop issues.  When matching (and beating) rs232 speeds, Ethernet is stupid easy and nearly free.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen  Indeed.  As my answer probably gives away, my advice to use galvanic isolation comes from past bitter experience.  My "top" problem was with -48V & +24V telco kit connected via a serial cable, where it turned out the incorrect use of a 48V-24V converter to power the 24V kit, meant its serial "ground" was actually at -24V relative to true ground.  When the serial connection was made, we discovered that typical RS232 wiring isn't rated for 100A+.  Very lucky the person making the connection avoided serious burns.